# Disable Wicket CheckGroup without disabling the rest of the form

Tags: wicket

I have a form with a `CheckGroup` and a `PropertyListView`. Each item in the list view has a `Check` belonging to the check group and a `AjaxFallbackLink`. When I disable the check group, the whole form gets disabled including the links. Similarly, when I set visible to false, the whole form is not visible.

```java
Form form = new Form("form");

CheckGroup checkGroup = new CheckGroup("checkGroup", checkList) {
    @Override
    protected void onConfigure() {
        super.onConfigure();
        setEnabled(isAuthorized());
    }
};  
checkGroup.add(new CheckGroupSelector("groupSelector"));
form.add(checkGroup);

PropertyListView<MyList> tableList = new PropertyListView<MyList>("table", new PropertyModel(lists, "myList")){
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<OfacCustomerMatchFile> item) {
        item.add(new Check("check", item.getModel(), checkGroup);
        item.add(new AjaxFallbackLink("itemLink") { ... });
    }
};
form.add(tableList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `#isEnabledHierarchy()` on your links:

```
public boolean isEnabledInHierarchy()
{
    return true;
}
```

Watch out, this can be dangerous since you are circumventing Wicket's default authorization handling.

Comment: Why the links are disabled at all ? They are not children of the CheckGroup. `Check`s are being disabled because of https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/fcec670558e9b8d01467748ea46c778321ecb4a4/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Check.java#L200

Comment: This did the trick. However, is there any way to make that check group only affect the checks? This worked easy enough for the scenario, but would be very cumbersome for multiple components per list item, or `isVisible()`.

Comment: Martin has a valid point: The links are not children of the checkGroup, so they shouldn't be disabled anyways - please check your code.